# Which one is better: in database?

Tags: mysql, database, jpa, database-design, system-design

I am working on a system using JPA where Entity 'Events' are associated with Entity 'Groups' and each Group has fields (Group1, Group2...) indicating their attendance status for an event.

How to design this?

Comment: Don't store this in the database at all. Use a query that calculates the number of attendees using `SUM(Group1), etc.`

Comment: MySQL already treats booleans as integers, with TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0. So SUM will do what you want.

Comment: @Barmar The groups (GROUP 1, GROUP 2, ...) are booleans. I am not sure how sum works here. Are you saying to change the data type from boolean to integer

Comment: There are 5 groups today?  Will there be 6th tomorrow?  Adding a column is possible, but clumsy.

Comment: No, I'm saying you don't need to. Booleans are integers in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Counter realization varies depending on how much you are non-tolerant to bad counts and how many counts can be affected by race conditions.

For your case you should have registration events for each user, so simpler just count it in another table by crontab and put stats somewhere(this table or new one, as you wish). That is easy, simple, error- and bad-coder tolerant.

Answer (score -1):

> Entity 'Events' are associated with Entity 'Groups' and each Group has five boolean columns (Group1, Group2...) indicating their attendance status for an event.

What do you mean by Entity Group has five boolean fields? Tip : you share the ER diagram of the current model and then go on about the new requirement.

> Now, I need to enhance the system by adding a feature that tracks the number of people attending the event for each group

Do you have a User table? You can create a junction table of (User - Event - Group). For finding the event attendance, you’d do a `Select count() from JunctionTable where eventId = x AND groupId = y.`

If you don’t have a User table, the junction entity can be of (Event - Group - count of people).
Although this second approach is slightly problematic if your app is supposed to to be highly concurrent, what if the there’s an event with large number of people from the same group coming in simultaneously? You’d have to lock the junction table record and increment one by one.

Please share the ER diagram, maybe I’m mistaken in my understanding of your current table shape.

Comment: Requests for clarification belong in comments & not in answer posts. If you need clarification, you shouldn't be making an answer post. While you do not have enough reputation to comment, wait; do not abuse site protocols. Guesses make bad answers & make a mess. A list of guesses is worse. [answer] [Help]

Comment: I have asked for clarification along with an answer from what I’ve understood from his problem statement. I’d have revised my answer if I got any new info. 

Also I don’t see anything in the How to answer page you’ve linked which says what I’ve done is frowned upon. 

How else am I suppsoed to even get the reputation to be able to ask for clarifications in the comment section of the question?

Comment: From [answer] at the [Help]: "**Answer [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions** Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... • ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem." But your comment & this comment are not necessary because in order to help you & the asker & the site & later Q&A readers I told you it was against site protocols but you have nevertheless chosen to excuse yourself. PS See also [meta] & [meta.SE] Q&A.

Comment: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/3404097)